# ¿Cómo muestro en un label los datos de un vector tipo string?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo **el juego del Ahorcado** en *Windows Form* y *C#*. Mi problema es ir mostrando letra por letra lo tecleado por el usuario.

```
if(stPalabra.Contains(stLetra.ToLower()))
{
    lblMensaje.Text = "¡Muy bien! Acertaste ingresando la letra "+stLetra;
    inAciertos = inAciertos+1;
    inpuntos = inpuntos+100;
    lblCantPun.Text = inPuntos.ToString();
    for(int i=0;i<stPalabra.Length;i++)
    {
        if(stPalabra.Substring(i,1)==stLetra.ToLower())
        {
            if(tsmFacil.Checked==true)
            {
                espaciosFacil[i] = stLetra;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En la sentencia `espaciosFacil[i] = stLetra;` guardo la letra presionada en la posición correspondiente de la palabra en un vector inicializado con guiones bajos "_". Mi problema es como ir mostrando en un label las letras de la palabra hasta formar la misma. Por ejemplo:

> "P _ O G _ _ M _ C I O _ " (PROGRAMACION).

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Por favor, lee el Artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Tu código debe estar copiado en texto y en formato código, no se aceptan imágenes de código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay muchas posibles soluciones. Una es usar `String.Join`:

```
tuLabel.Text = String.Join("",espaciosFacil);
```

Comment: Es buena idea, pero de esa manera me va pisando letra por letra a medida que ingreso. Yo necesito que por ejemplo si se ingresa una letra correcta, se muestren todas las posiciones (guiones bajos) y la letra correcta en la/s posicion/es (reemplazando el guion bajo).

Comment: No entiendo @AguFortini. Estás inicializando `espaciosFacil` con cada tecla pulsada?

Comment: Nono, así : `string[] espaciosFacil = { "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_" };`

Comment: Si,eso lo entiendo, pero lo inicializas cada vez que se pulsa una tecla? es que no entiendo a que te refieres lo de _me va pisando letra por letra a medida que ingreso_.Si tu inicializas `espaciosFacil` al principio, con la nueva palabra a adivinar, y vas sustituyendo los `_` con las letras a medida que se van pulsando, en `espaciosFacil` tendrias algo asi como `{"P","_","O", "G", "_", "_", "M", "_", "C", "I", "O", "_" }`. Si no es asi, pega mas codigo para que entendamos

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que si utilizo `tuLabel.Text = String.Join("",espaciosFacil);` si por ejemplo la palabra es HOLA, presiono la H, y en el label me muestra la H, presiono la L y me muestra solo la L, descartando la H y asi sucesivamente, osea me termina mostrando solo la última tecla presionada.

Comment: Lee mi comentario anterior. Eso es porque inicializas `espaciosFacil` con cada tecla pulsada.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo los comentarios arme un pequeño programa de consola para jugar al ahorcado. Es una muestra básica.

El método adivinar hace el reemplazo por el carácter que adivino o el oculto para mantener el progreso del juego.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Ahorcado
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string palabra = "Hola";
        string oculta = new string('_', palabra.Length);

        for (int intentos = 0; intentos < 3; intentos++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una letra:");
            oculta = Adivinar(palabra, oculta, Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);
            Console.WriteLine(">" + oculta);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Fin del juego");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string Adivinar(string palabra, string oculta, char presiono)
    {
        StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder();
        bool acerto = palabra.Contains(presiono);

        if (acerto)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < palabra.Length; i++)
            {
                if (palabra[i] == presiono)
                {
                    resultado.Append(palabra[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    resultado.Append(oculta[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            resultado.Append(oculta);
        }

        return resultado.ToString();
    }
}
}
```